# Information about Leaflet and MapGuide

Tags: leaflet, web-mapping, software-recommendations, mapguide

I want to make interactive maps online/on a server but not sure whether leaflet or MapGuide program is better for me to delve into.

Which software will allow me to render resource intensive layers quickly?
Which software is most compatible with QGIS?
Which software would allow users to switch between up to 30 mutually exclusive layers?
Which software is easier to update a couple of layers without having to re-do to much?

Comment: Are you wanting to set up services as well, or are just interested in the client (Leaflet/MapGuide).  When you say compatible with QGIS what do you mean?